# Getting started with Karma and Jasmine installed - jasmine.Suite() required error

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, resharper, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to get started with karma and jasmine.

I've installed them both. I believe that Karma can locate my JavaScript files. When I run `karma start`, my browsers open and state:

```
Karma v0.12.23 - connected
IE 11.0.0 (Windows 8.1) is idle
Firefox 29.0.0 (Windows 8.1) is idle
Chrome 37.0.2062 (Windows 8.1) is idle
```

I added a JavaScript file to a location that I thought Karma was monitoring:

```
it('y should have a length of 1', function () {
    var y = '1';
    expect(y.length).toBe(0);
});
```

Where would I look to see the unit test fail?

If I open resharper in vs2013, I see the unit test. When I go to run it, a new browser window opens, and it's blank. The console does show on this page:

```
ncaught Error: jasmine.Suite() required
```

How do I get it to pick up my test?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As described in the Jasmine nomenclature a suite

> Suites: describe Your Tests
>
> A test suite begins with a call to the global Jasmine function describe with two parameters: a string and a function. The string is a name or title for a spec suite – usually what is being tested. The function is a block of code that implements the suite.

So I guess you have to wrap your test in a `describe statement`

```
describe('my test suite',function(){
    
    it('my test case',function(){
        //some assertions
    })
});
```